# How SBT multi-project share the same actor system

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, projects-and-solutions, class-hierarchy

I'm working on a SBT multi-project solution.

Now I have:

- top project test-env
- sub project test-core
- sub project test-proj1
- sub project test-proj2

Hierarchy like this:

test-env

- src
- project
- build.sbt
- test-core

  - src
  - build.sbt
- test-proj1

  - src
  - build.sbt
- test-proj2

  - src
  - build.sbt

I want to put some main function and object like akka ActorSystem in test-core which could be refered in test-proj1 and test-proj2.
This could be done by writting project dependence in test-env's build.sbt like this:

```
val env = (project in file(".")) 
val core = (project in file("test-core"))
    .aggregate(proj1,proj2)
    .settings(
        run / aggregate := true
    )
lazy val coreRef = LocalProject("core") 
lazy val proj1 = (project in file("test-proj1")).dependsOn(coreRef) 
lazy val proj2 = (project in file("test-proj2")).dependsOn(coreRef)
```

But the problem is :
When I refer the ActorSystem defined in test-core through test-proj1 and test-proj2.They are not the same ActorSystem.
And I don't want to put all of them into a single project and make proj1 and proj2 as a package.
So How can I refer the same ActorSystem by this project hierarchy ?

Comment: Actors exist at run time. They have absolutely no relation with sbt, maven or gradle. Actor Systems are runtime entities in a JVM, so all the actor in the same JVM application can share the same ActorSystem. Or even some other JVM application can interact with an ActorSystem which allows remote interactions.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yes,ActorSystem has no relationship with sbt. I just want to use the same ActorSystem instance in proj1,proj2 and core when they are running.Not three ActorSystems interacting with each other.And I still want to orgnize the project on subproj level not package level.  And I want to figure out How or Why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two sub project have two main function.
two main function means two application.
two application means two process.
two process means sharing nothing by default.

So The sub project hierarchy talking above can't resolve "the same ActorSystem instance" problem.